# Spring data mongodb update custom field

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I have an ***_id*** of mongodb object and want to update only a specific field in DB. Is there a way not to get the entire object with ***findone(id)*** then set required field and ***save*** to mongodb again? I want something like ***sql update*** mechanism which  didn't find in mongodb yet. 
I use java Spring data.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using [spring-data-mongodb](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/),

[MongoTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html) has convenient methods for [update](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#updateMulti-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update-java.lang.Class-)/[upsert](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#upsert-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update-java.lang.Class-).